# Conditions for Martingale

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, martingales

Let $X{}_{1},X_{2},\ldots$be a sequence of independent RV and let
$f{}_{j}$be continuous functions. Let $S{}_{0}=1$ and $S{}_{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}f_{j}\left(X_{j}\right)$.
Find a necessary and sufficient conditino so that $S{}_{n}$ is a
martingale.

Comment: You need to specify a filtration and add your own thoughts on the exercise.